# How can I use cURL to INSERT into mySQL?

Tags: php, curl

Not sure is it the right way 
My plan,I have 2 file first curl second insert

first

```
$url = "localhost/insert.php";
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $txt);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $ret = curl_close($ch);
```

second

```
    $db = new PDO('mssql:host=192.168.1.1;dbname=code_2', 'user','pass');
    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `code`(`id`, `rcode`) VALUES ( :campaign , :code )");
    $sql->bindValue( ":campaign" , 5 , PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $sql->bindValue( ":code" , 5 , PDO::PARAM_STR );
.....
```

Is it the right way ? How can second get data ? or I use it wrong way ?

any tutorial or guide or advice ?

Comment: Please tell us why you'd want to do that. Are the files on two different servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your data in the $txt variable like this

```
$txt = "user=beer&pass=isgood"
```

And then in your instert.php you can access it as

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
```

However i don't think this is a good idea to transfer data between files. Consider using ajax from the front end instead if its possible

Comment: And don't forget proper escaping to prevent sql injections. Edit: Didn't see the ->prepare(...). So no problem here :D

Comment: Oh I just use this way too. :) But I'm not have skill in ajax.could you show any guide/tutorial ?
ps.found in minute later after post question

Comment: in your html something like this

<script>
    jQuery.post("insert.php", {
       "user": "beer",
       "pass": "isgood"
    }, function(response){
        /// process response here
    });
</script>

Make sure you are not exposing sensitive data and ALWAYS escape user input before interacting with the db